# Which tool/reference for address geocoding?

Tags: qgis, postgis, mapinfo, geocoding, tiger

I have to geocode several corporate sites (a big excel file), close to Paris (France). I would like to geocode this file based on the addresses.

1. Could you tell me the best tool for this task (accuracy, performance, ease of use, etc.). On my station, I have  Qgis, postgis, mapinfo
2. Is it better to use a web tool or a desktop GIS?
3. I guess I must have a reference database for the streets network?  How do I choose it? And how do I get it?

Comment: This is actually 3 questions. Also you haven't really given us enough information to go on. A couple of sample addresses might help.

Comment: Are you aware of [Nomiatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding Nominatim, i have just read the official page. But i don't understand very well? Nominatim is  a webtool or a database(vector reference)?

Comment: It is web based. I am not sure what you mean by point 3. Would you be able to provide a couple of samples of your data -- geocoding is very susceptible to mispelling and the like.

Answer (score 1):

1) For one time solutions Google Fusion Tables may be usefull. You can upload excel, geocode there and then download different formats.
2) For DB solution check Tiger Geocoder for Postgis/postgresql

Comment: As the question references France, i dont think TIGER data is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got QGIS, the **[MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/)** plugin has a pretty cool Geocoding function where you can load a .CSV file and utilise Google and/or OSM (or even your own road/address data) to create some points and write them to a Shapefile.

[image]

The quality of your Geocode would be dependent on the quality of your input data as well as the quality of Google and OSM themselves.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/ 
You have to use your own API-key but apart from that it works quite well.
If you want set up your own service you can use gisgraphy http://www.gisgraphy.com